# Homepage showing a simple listing of title, featured image, then posted on

Tags: themes, child-theme

Here's a link to my blog which uses the Bushwick theme: http://veegan.co.uk/

It's current format is to have the most recent post at the top, with a larger title, then the entire post, then the post date. The other posts are listed below this in smaller text and without any pictures or content.

Ideally I'd like something where they're all the same size and have the title, the featured image, and then the posted on date.

Here's the current index.php:

```
    <?php
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php
                get_template_part( 'navigation' );

                if ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();

                    /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content' );

                    while ( have_posts() ) :
                        the_post();

                        get_template_part( 'content', 'preview' );
                    endwhile;

                    bushwick_paging_nav();

                else :
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
                endif;
            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer();
```

I've tried a few different things, including replacing `the_post();` with `the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail');` but for some reason it doesn't change what appears on the screen at all.

As a middle ground I tried changing `the_post();` to `the_excerpt();` and it seemed to loop through almost hundreds of times, showing the same excerpt over and over again.

I'm at a bit of a loss with this and would any advice would be great, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like there are two parts to your query: 1) Stop the first post from showing the full content, and 2) show the featured image on all the posts.

1) At the moment, the first post is using a different template to the other posts. To make the posts consistent, change this in *index.php*:

`get_template_part( 'content' );`

to this:

`get_template_part( 'content', 'preview' );`

2) Once all posts are using the same template, you'll need to edit that template. Edit the file named *content-preview.php*. Directly below the code that starts with `<?php the_title...`, enter the following code to display your thumbnails:

`<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much! That's perfect :D Super useful, and you've really helped me understand the way the themes are generated. Thanks!